# C# serializing JSON data from Database for API

Tags: c#, json, database, api, parsing

My goal is to get the data from the database, serializing them into JSON format and send it to the API. The problem is that I don't know how to get right JSON format for the API.

C# *Worker service* collecting data from database.

from database i got:

`1|John|Wick|Action|101`

my API needs this JSON:

```
{ 
     "Name":"John",
     "Surname":"Wick",
     "Type":"Action",
     "Length":"101"
}
```

when i use in *C#* serializing to JSON:

```
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

i got:

```
[John,Wick,Action,101]
```

is there any way how to add name of values to JSON ?

Comment: You need a class, create an instance of it with the values loaded from the database (this could be done by an ORM like Dapper or EF) and then serialize with the overload that takes the type. Like _SerializeObject<ClassType>(classInstance)_

Comment: You meant to write serializing, not parsing. Parsing is the act of converting a string into an object, serializing is the inverse of that. I updated your question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split the database result based on the delimiter

```
string dbResult = ...;  //1|John|Wick|Action|101
string[] dbResults = dbResult.Split("|");
```

Second create an anonymous object (if you don't want to introduce a data model `class`/`struct`/`record`)

```
var result = new 
{
  Name = dbResults[0],
  Surname = dbResults[1],
  Type = dbResults[2],
  Length = dbResults[3],
};
```

Third serialize the anonymous object

```
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```